# How to Map ILOFFSET to generated xml using PDB2XML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment, pdb-files

How can we map ILOFFSET to generated xml using PDB2XML . I'm logging ILOFFSET from code . but I'm not able map it to xml file generated. Here is my xml file generated.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/08/25/pdb2xml.aspx) is the sample code

```html
<SymbolData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" assembly="D:\Projects\Sources\bakUp\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\bin\WebApplication1.dll">
<sourceFiles>
     <document id="1" url="D:\Projects\Sources\BakUp\WebApplication1          \WebApplication1\About.aspx.cs"    language="3f5162f8-07c6-11d3-9053-00c04fa302a1" languageVendor="994b45c4-e6e9-11d2-903f-00c04fa302a1" documentType="5a869d0b-6611-11d3-bd2a-0000f80849bd"/>
<document id="2" url="D:\Projects\Sources\BakUp\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.cs" language="3f5162f8-07c6-11d3-9053-00c04fa302a1" languageVendor="994b45c4-e6e9-11d2-903f-00c04fa302a1" documentType="5a869d0b-6611-11d3-bd2a-0000f80849bd"/>
<document id="3" url="D:\Projects\Sources\BakUp\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Global.asax.cs" language="3f5162f8-07c6-11d3-9053-00c04fa302a1" languageVendor="994b45c4-e6e9-11d2-903f-00c04fa302a1" documentType="5a869d0b-6611-11d3-bd2a-0000f80849bd"/>
<document id="4" url="D:\Projects\Sources\BakUp\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Account\Login.aspx.cs" language="3f5162f8-07c6-11d3-9053-00c04fa302a1" languageVendor="994b45c4-e6e9-11d2-903f-00c04fa302a1" documentType="5a869d0b-6611-11d3-bd2a-0000f80849bd"/>
<document id="5" url="D:\Projects\Sources\BakUp\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Account\Register.aspx.cs" language="3f5162f8-07c6-11d3-9053-00c04fa302a1" languageVendor="994b45c4-e6e9-11d2-903f-00c04fa302a1" documentType="5a869d0b-6611-11d3-bd2a-0000f80849bd"/>
<document id="6" url="D:\Projects\Sources\BakUp\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Account\ChangePassword.aspx.cs" language="3f5162f8-07c6-11d3-9053-00c04fa302a1" languageVendor="994b45c4-e6e9-11d2-903f-00c04fa302a1" documentType="5a869d0b-6611-11d3-bd2a-0000f80849bd"/>
<document id="7" url="D:\Projects\Sources\BakUp\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Site.Master.cs" language="3f5162f8-07c6-11d3-9053-00c04fa302a1" languageVendor="994b45c4-e6e9-11d2-903f-00c04fa302a1" documentType="5a869d0b-6611-11d3-bd2a-0000f80849bd"/>
<document id="8" url="D:\Projects\Sources\BakUp\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Account\ChangePasswordSuccess.aspx.cs" language="3f5162f8-07c6-11d3-9053-00c04fa302a1" languageVendor="994b45c4-e6e9-11d2-903f-00c04fa302a1" documentType="5a869d0b-6611-11d3-bd2a-0000f80849bd"/>
</sourceFiles>
<method name="WebApplication1.About::Page_Load" token="0x6000001">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="1" startRow="13" startColumn="9" endRow="13" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="1" startRow="15" startColumn="9" endRow="15" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<usingNamespace name="USystem"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Collections.Generic"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Linq"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
</scope>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<using version="4">
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>6</countOfUsing>
</using>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1._Default::Page_Load" token="0x6000003">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="2" startRow="18" startColumn="9" endRow="18" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="2" startRow="19" startColumn="13" endRow="19" endColumn="24"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="8" sourceId="2" startRow="20" startColumn="9" endRow="20" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="9">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="9">
<usingNamespace name="USystem"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Collections.Generic"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Linq"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.IO"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Xml"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Diagnostics"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Text"/>
</scope>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<using version="4">
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>10</countOfUsing>
</using>
<usingForwardToModule version="4" tokenOfModuleInfo="0x6000001"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1._Default::Checking" token="0x6000004" localSigMetadataToken="0x11000001">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="2" startRow="23" startColumn="9" endRow="23" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="2" startRow="24" startColumn="13" endRow="24" endColumn="34"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="3" sourceId="2" startRow="25" startColumn="13" endRow="25" endColumn="29"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="5" sourceId="2" startRow="27" startColumn="13" endRow="27" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="6" sourceId="2" startRow="29" startColumn="17" endRow="29" endColumn="44"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="12" sourceId="2" startRow="30" startColumn="17" endRow="30" endColumn="30"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="18" sourceId="2" startRow="31" startColumn="17" endRow="31" endColumn="66"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="29" sourceId="2" startRow="36" startColumn="13" endRow="36" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="30" sourceId="2" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="35" sourceId="2" startRow="37" startColumn="13" endRow="37" endColumn="33"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="37" sourceId="2" startRow="38" startColumn="13" endRow="38" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="38" sourceId="2" startRow="47" startColumn="17" endRow="47" endColumn="51"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="45" sourceId="2" startRow="54" startColumn="17" endRow="54" endColumn="71"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="69" sourceId="2" startRow="55" startColumn="17" endRow="55" endColumn="24"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="70" sourceId="2" startRow="55" startColumn="46" endRow="55" endColumn="61"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="79" sourceId="2" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="87" sourceId="2" startRow="55" startColumn="26" endRow="55" endColumn="42"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="94" sourceId="2" startRow="56" startColumn="17" endRow="56" endColumn="18"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="95" sourceId="2" startRow="57" startColumn="21" endRow="60" endColumn="169"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="289" sourceId="2" startRow="63" startColumn="17" endRow="63" endColumn="18"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="290" sourceId="2" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="296" sourceId="2" startRow="55" startColumn="43" endRow="55" endColumn="45"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="306" sourceId="2" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="313" sourceId="2" startRow="67" startColumn="13" endRow="67" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="314" sourceId="2" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="316" sourceId="2" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="317" sourceId="2" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="319" sourceId="2" startRow="69" startColumn="13" endRow="69" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="320" sourceId="2" startRow="70" startColumn="17" endRow="70" endColumn="32"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="326" sourceId="2" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="330" sourceId="2" startRow="71" startColumn="21" endRow="71" endColumn="32"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="337" sourceId="2" startRow="72" startColumn="13" endRow="72" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="338" sourceId="2" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="339" sourceId="2" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="340" sourceId="2" startRow="73" startColumn="9" endRow="73" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="341">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="341">
<local name="CS$6$0000" ilIndex="7" attributes="1" signature="1D128091"/>
<local name="CS$7$0001" ilIndex="8" attributes="1" signature="08"/>
<local name="CS$0$0002" ilIndex="9" attributes="1" signature="1D1C"/>
<local name="CS$0$0003" ilIndex="10" attributes="1" signature="08"/>
<local name="CS$4$0004" ilIndex="11" attributes="1" signature="02"/>
<local name="fs" ilIndex="0" attributes="0" signature="1280AD"/>
<local name="linenum" ilIndex="1" attributes="0" signature="08"/>
<scope startOffset="5" endOffset="30">
<local name="king" ilIndex="2" attributes="0" signature="0E"/>
<local name="value2" ilIndex="3" attributes="0" signature="0E"/>
</scope>
<scope startOffset="37" endOffset="314">
<local name="ex" ilIndex="4" attributes="0" signature="128089"/>
<local name="st1" ilIndex="5" attributes="0" signature="128085"/>
<scope startOffset="70" endOffset="313">
<local name="frame" ilIndex="6" attributes="0" signature="128091"/>
</scope>
</scope>
</scope>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<usingForward version="4" tokenToForwardTo="0x6000003"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.Global::Application_Start" token="0x6000006">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="3" startRow="14" startColumn="9" endRow="14" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="3" startRow="17" startColumn="9" endRow="17" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<usingNamespace name="USystem"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Collections.Generic"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Linq"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.Security"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.SessionState"/>
</scope>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<using version="4">
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>6</countOfUsing>
</using>
<usingForwardToModule version="4" tokenOfModuleInfo="0x6000001"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.Global::Application_End" token="0x6000007">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="3" startRow="20" startColumn="9" endRow="20" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="3" startRow="23" startColumn="9" endRow="23" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="2" isReconstructedDueToDiasymreaderBug="true"/>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<usingForward version="4" tokenToForwardTo="0x6000006"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.Global::Application_Error" token="0x6000008">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="3" startRow="26" startColumn="9" endRow="26" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="3" startRow="29" startColumn="9" endRow="29" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="2" isReconstructedDueToDiasymreaderBug="true"/>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<usingForward version="4" tokenToForwardTo="0x6000006"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.Global::Session_Start" token="0x6000009">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="3" startRow="32" startColumn="9" endRow="32" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="3" startRow="35" startColumn="9" endRow="35" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="2" isReconstructedDueToDiasymreaderBug="true"/>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<usingForward version="4" tokenToForwardTo="0x6000006"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.Global::Session_End" token="0x600000a">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="3" startRow="38" startColumn="9" endRow="38" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="3" startRow="44" startColumn="9" endRow="44" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="2" isReconstructedDueToDiasymreaderBug="true"/>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<usingForward version="4" tokenToForwardTo="0x6000006"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.Account.Login::Page_Load" token="0x600000c">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="4" startRow="13" startColumn="9" endRow="13" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="4" startRow="14" startColumn="13" endRow="14" endColumn="130"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="49" sourceId="4" startRow="15" startColumn="9" endRow="15" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="50">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="50">
<usingNamespace name="USystem"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Collections.Generic"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Linq"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
</scope>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<using version="4">
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>6</countOfUsing>
</using>
<usingForwardToModule version="4" tokenOfModuleInfo="0x6000001"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.Account.Register::Page_Load" token="0x600000e">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="5" startRow="15" startColumn="9" endRow="15" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="5" startRow="16" startColumn="13" endRow="16" endColumn="88"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="34" sourceId="5" startRow="17" startColumn="9" endRow="17" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="35">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="35">
<usingNamespace name="USystem"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Collections.Generic"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Linq"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.Security"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
</scope>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<using version="4">
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>7</countOfUsing>
</using>
<usingForwardToModule version="4" tokenOfModuleInfo="0x6000001"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.Account.Register::RegisterUser_CreatedUser" token="0x600000f" localSigMetadataToken="0x11000002">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="5" startRow="20" startColumn="9" endRow="20" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="5" startRow="21" startColumn="13" endRow="21" endColumn="106"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="19" sourceId="5" startRow="23" startColumn="13" endRow="23" endColumn="74"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="31" sourceId="5" startRow="24" startColumn="13" endRow="24" endColumn="51"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="41" sourceId="5" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="44" sourceId="5" startRow="25" startColumn="13" endRow="25" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="45" sourceId="5" startRow="26" startColumn="17" endRow="26" endColumn="36"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="51" sourceId="5" startRow="27" startColumn="13" endRow="27" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="52" sourceId="5" startRow="28" startColumn="13" endRow="28" endColumn="44"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="65" sourceId="5" startRow="29" startColumn="9" endRow="29" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="66">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="66">
<local name="CS$4$0000" ilIndex="1" attributes="1" signature="02"/>
<local name="continueUrl" ilIndex="0" attributes="0" signature="0E"/>
</scope>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<usingForward version="4" tokenToForwardTo="0x600000e"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.Account.ChangePassword::Page_Load" token="0x6000011">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="6" startRow="13" startColumn="9" endRow="13" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="6" startRow="15" startColumn="9" endRow="15" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<usingNamespace name="USystem"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Collections.Generic"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Linq"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
</scope>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<using version="4">
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>6</countOfUsing>
</using>
<usingForwardToModule version="4" tokenOfModuleInfo="0x6000001"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.SiteMaster::Page_Load" token="0x6000013" localSigMetadataToken="0x11000003">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="7" startRow="15" startColumn="9" endRow="15" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="7" startRow="17" startColumn="13" endRow="17" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="2" sourceId="7" startRow="18" startColumn="17" endRow="18" endColumn="66"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="13" sourceId="7" startRow="19" startColumn="13" endRow="19" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="14" sourceId="7" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="19" sourceId="7" startRow="20" startColumn="13" endRow="20" endColumn="33"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="20" sourceId="7" startRow="21" startColumn="13" endRow="21" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="21" sourceId="7" startRow="30" startColumn="17" endRow="30" endColumn="51"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="27" sourceId="7" startRow="37" startColumn="17" endRow="37" endColumn="69"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="50" sourceId="7" startRow="38" startColumn="17" endRow="38" endColumn="24"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="51" sourceId="7" startRow="38" startColumn="46" endRow="38" endColumn="61"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="59" sourceId="7" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="67" sourceId="7" startRow="38" startColumn="26" endRow="38" endColumn="42"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="73" sourceId="7" startRow="39" startColumn="17" endRow="39" endColumn="18"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="74" sourceId="7" startRow="40" startColumn="21" endRow="43" endColumn="165"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="263" sourceId="7" startRow="46" startColumn="17" endRow="46" endColumn="18"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="264" sourceId="7" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="270" sourceId="7" startRow="38" startColumn="43" endRow="38" endColumn="45"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="280" sourceId="7" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="287" sourceId="7" startRow="47" startColumn="13" endRow="47" endColumn="14"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="288" sourceId="7" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="290" sourceId="7" hidden="true" startRow="16707566" startColumn="0" endRow="16707566" endColumn="0"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="291" sourceId="7" startRow="48" startColumn="9" endRow="48" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="292">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="292">
<local name="CS$6$0000" ilIndex="4" attributes="1" signature="1D128091"/>
<local name="CS$7$0001" ilIndex="5" attributes="1" signature="08"/>
<local name="CS$0$0002" ilIndex="6" attributes="1" signature="1D1C"/>
<local name="CS$0$0003" ilIndex="7" attributes="1" signature="08"/>
<local name="CS$4$0004" ilIndex="8" attributes="1" signature="02"/>
<scope startOffset="1" endOffset="14">
<local name="value2" ilIndex="0" attributes="0" signature="0E"/>
</scope>
<scope startOffset="20" endOffset="288">
<local name="ex" ilIndex="1" attributes="0" signature="128089"/>
<local name="st1" ilIndex="2" attributes="0" signature="128085"/>
<scope startOffset="51" endOffset="287">
<local name="frame" ilIndex="3" attributes="0" signature="128091"/>
</scope>
</scope>
<usingNamespace name="USystem"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Collections.Generic"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Linq"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.IO"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Diagnostics"/>
</scope>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<using version="4">
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>8</countOfUsing>
</using>
<usingForwardToModule version="4" tokenOfModuleInfo="0x6000001"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
<method name="WebApplication1.Account.ChangePasswordSuccess::Page_Load" token="0x6000015">
<sequencePoints>
<seqPoint ilOffset="0" sourceId="8" startRow="13" startColumn="9" endRow="13" endColumn="10"/>
<seqPoint ilOffset="1" sourceId="8" startRow="15" startColumn="9" endRow="15" endColumn="10"/>
</sequencePoints>
<rootScope implicit="true" startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<scope startOffset="0" endOffset="2">
<usingNamespace name="USystem"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Collections.Generic"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Linq"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI"/>
<usingNamespace name="USystem.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
</scope>
</rootScope>
<symAttributes/>
<csharpCustomDebugInfo version="4">
<entries>
<using version="4">
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>0</countOfUsing>
<countOfUsing>6</countOfUsing>
</using>
<usingForwardToModule version="4" tokenOfModuleInfo="0x6000001"/>
</entries>
</csharpCustomDebugInfo>
</method>
</SymbolData>
```

Here is my code I have Implemented for logging ILOFFSET.
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Checking();
        }

```
    private void Checking()
    {
        FileStream fs = null;
        int linenum = 0;
        try
        {
            // string value1 = File.ReadAllText("C:\\file.txt");

            string value2 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.txt");
            //Pdb2XmlConverter pdbReader = new Pdb2XmlConverter(xw, @"D:\ZeroChaosProject\ZeroChaos\ZeroChaos\ZerochaosWeb\ZCW\Bin\ZCW.dll");
            //pdbReader.ReadPdbAndWriteToXml();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  Console.WriteLine("[Data File Missing] {0}", e);

            //lblProductionStackTrace.Text = ExceptionReporting.GetExceptionReport(ex);

            //lblError.Text = ex.StackTrace;

            //lblError.Text = lblError.Text + "*****************" + lblError.Text + ExceptionEx.ToProductionString(ex).ToString();

            StackTrace st1 = new StackTrace();
            //// StackTrace st1 = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true));
            //// lblStackFrame.Text = " Stack Trace with Stack Frame: {0}" + st1.ToString() + StackFrame.OFFSET_UNKNOWN + "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^";
            ////  lblStackTrace.Text = st.ToString();

            //linenum = ex.LineNumber();

            lblStackFrame.Text = ex.GetBaseException().ToString(); 
            foreach (StackFrame frame in st1.GetFrames())
            {
                lblStackFrame.Text =   "at " + frame.GetMethod().Module.Name + "." +
                    frame.GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name + "."
                    + frame.GetMethod().Name
                    + "  (IL offset: 0x" + frame.GetILOffset().ToString("x") + ")\n" + "MataData Token : " + frame.GetMethod().MetadataToken + lblStackFrame.Text  ;


            }

            //var trace = ExceptionReporting.GetExceptionReport(ex);
            //Label1.Text = "ProductionStackTrace : " + trace;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fs != null)
                fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: Get Line numbers without deploying pdb files. I trying to implement this link. http://www.timstall.com/2008/07/getting-file-and-line-numbers-without.html

Comment: Without a PDB you will not get a (reliable) ILOffset as far as I know.

Comment: I have read that .Net CLR will load the line numbers using the ILOFFSET(bridge between code executed and to get line numbers from PDB files) . http://www.lionhack.com/2014/01/28/stack-trace-line-numbers-without-deploying-pdbs/ . Stackframe will be having the ILOFFSET of each and every frame.

Comment: " This offset might be an approximation depending on whether or not the just-in-time (JIT) compiler is generating debugging code. " As said, not reliable.